# Moving a Wordpress Multisite site to a new install

Tags: multisite, migration

Is it possible to move a WP site from one network to another?

I have a Wordpress multisite and I'd like to take one of the sites and move it into a new multisite installation.

Comment: If you mean server, yes. I do it every day. We are moving all the WP sites from our servers to HostGator. It's actually very simple.

Comment: It's possible, yes. What problems are you running into?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not clear what the actual problem is. Please read [ask].

Comment: Changes made to make the question more clear.

Comment: I do it all the time.  WordPress has handy [import](http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Import_SubPanel) and [export](http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen) facilities under the **Tools** menu in the `wp-admin` pages.  Export your site from the old network, and then import it on the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is check the docs: [Tools Export Screen « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen) and [Importing Content « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content)

You can move the site content as a WXR file and import the images and attachments on WXR import.